# Why do some Youtube Videos dont have proper fileDetails in Youtube Data API V3?

Tags: c#, .net, youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

I have a Software which should upload videos to my Youtube-Profile.

The process is:

1. Retrieve Uploaded Videos and extract Filenames
2. Check Filenames to the one of the video to be uploaded
3. If Video is not already uploaded (so it is not in the File-List) then upload it

But I came across the issue that a video (which I have uploaded shortly before) doesn't have a `fileName` so it is an empty string.

So my Question is now do Videos which where Uploaded via the Youtube API always lack in these kind of informations or will this data be available some time after the upload?

Comment: Do you see the filename in Youtube Studio ?

Comment: Thats a good point @novaXire . What if there is also no Filename? I mean it has actually a filename on OS level. And I can't send the Filename as a parameter on upload...

Comment: @Snickbrack "I can't send the Filename as a parameter on upload" could you precise how you upload a video ? On my side `fileDetails` returns correctly the `fileName`, has the bug been solved since you asked your question ?